# How Change Viewport for iOS websites?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, browser

I'm working on a website which has three possible views:

1. mobile
2. pad
3. full

It should switch from mobile to pad on a "normal" mobile device if the user turns its mobilephone to the landscape view.

I've already tested it with Android (Samsung Galaxy SIII) and there it works.
My problem is that iOS devices (like iPhone 5) doesn't change there view-port width when the user turns it into landscape mode. (Landscape is activated, both views return 320px inner window width on iPhone)

How can I fix it?

Comment: How and when do you check the width?

Comment: did you set the meta viewport tag correctly?

Comment: Viewport Settings: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` Width checks: a mix of javascript window.innerWidth and css @import conditions

Comment: I have never had problems with iOS and css @media conditions. However, I can say that I have never had to conditionally execute JS based on screen width/height.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` had to be `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`

With that the standard view-port scale of the device is applied.
Thanks Jeff Shaver for the question ;D